# Localize Android application so I can switch locale inside app

Tags: android, localization

How do I localize application so it uses specific locale regardless of what locale set on device? I want make it possible for users to set language of their choice.

So far I have code like this in my Application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    //Set locale
    String l = Preferences.getLocale(getApplicationContext());
    if (!l.equals(""))
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale(l);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(
            config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    LogData.InsertMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Application started");
}
```

Problem that I have is that it seems like I display in set locale just fine (TextViews)
But Menu captions and toasts will fall to default locale.

Is there any 1-2-3 on how to get it working properly? I uses 2.2 version

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? Do you expect your users to have their device set to one language and want your app to use a different one?

Comment: @Noah Just today we had an issue. All users in and but some phones like IVO do not allow anything but English/Spanish. Allowing localizing at app level really helps those people.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured why I had this problem.. I needed to override `onConfigurationChanged` in my application class. That is much more elegant solution than to specify locale on each `Activity`.